# How to do power analysis for a linear mixed-effects model with *multiple predictors*?

Tags: multiple-regression, mixed-model, statistical-power

**QUESTION**: How would power analysis be done for ***each*** predictor in a linear mixed-effects model (LMM) with both Level 1 and Level 2 predictors?

I have scoured the web for resources on how to do power analysis on LMMs but all of the papers I found talk about the specific case/model where the design is repeated-measures and there's one Level-1 manipulation/treatment, which takes the general form: $y_{ijk} = \gamma_{00} + \gamma_{10}x_1 + u_{0j} + u_{1j}x_1 + e_{ijk} $ and $x_1$ is whether the treatment is present or not.

However, I have a cross-classified LMM with both Level-1 ($x$) and Level-2 ($w$) predictors with the following form:

Level 1: $y_{ijk} = \beta_{0jk} + \beta_{1j}x_1 + \beta_{2j}x_2 +\beta_{3}x_1x_2 + e_{ijk} $

Level 2:  $\beta_{0jk}=\gamma_{00} + \gamma_{01}w_1 + u_{0j} + u_{0k}$

$\beta_{1j}=\gamma_{10} + u_{1j}$

$\beta_{2j}=\gamma_{20} + u_{1j}$

where $x_1$ is a treatment/manipulation variable, $x_2$ is a continuous item-characteristic predictor (e.g., word length), and $w_1$ is a continuous individual-characteristic predictor (e.g., vocabulary). I have access to all the relevant variance-covariance terms.

I want to perform a power analysis for each of the 4 effects I have in my model (i.e., three main effects and the interaction effect), but I can't find a resource that goes over how to do so, much less discuss it, in the more general case where there are multiple predictors at both levels of the LMM. On the face of it, this suggests that the procedure to do so is similar to the one-manipulation case that the resources I found discuss. But partitioning variance at Level 2 vs. Level 1 is different, so there's reason to think that the procedure would be different for LMMs with multiple predictors at both levels. So I'm turning to this forum to hopefully get some insight from someone who has expertise in power analyses, particularly with LMMs. Thanks so much in advance!